# Prove that if $J \subset S$ is a principal ideal of $S$, then $f^{-1}(J)$ is a principal ideal of $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ and $S$ be commutative rings with unity $1_R$ and $1_S$ respectively, and let $f: R \to S$ be a ring isomorphism . Prove that if $J \subset S$ is a principal ideal of $S$, then $f^{-1}(J)$ is a principal ideal of $R$.

I am at a loss. Any help is welcome, thank you.

Comment: Hint : if $J=(y)$ and $y=f(x)$, then take a look at $(x)$, principal ideal of $R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $J$ be generated by $x \in S$. Because $f$ is a ring isomorphism,  $I=f^{-1}(J)$ is an ideal in $R$. It is generated by $f(x)$, because given $j\in J$, write $f^{-1}(j)=ax$ for some $a\in R$. Then
$j=f(a)f(x)$. Hence $I=\langle f(x)\rangle$.